# Hanged program not shown up in process explorer

Tags: windows-10, process

This is something bugging me for more than a decade. Occasionally there is a program hang in Windows (in this case a setup program in Windows 10 Pro), I tried to close it from resource monitor and it disappeared after a while. However the window is still shown and I cannot open a new copy of the program. I launched Process Explorer from sysinternals but this window doesn't show in the list.

What's going on? How can I shut it down without rebooting? Thanks~~

Comment: Use Process Explorer and drag the bull's-eye icon over the window to find its process.

Comment: Thanks, I found it at the bottom with a different name, probably why I overlooked it at the beginning.

Comment: I added an answer. If it was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

To find out which process is issuing a certain message, use
[Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

Drag the bull's-eye icon over the window to select its process.
You may then use the <kbd>Del</kbd> key or the right-click context menu
to kill the process.